# Creating dictionary of functions with symbols as keys

Tags: julia

I am trying to create a dictionary of functions with symbols as keys but I am getting an error. I have tried the following:

```
functions = Dict{
                    :gauss => (v::Float64)->gauss(v, 0.0, 1.0),
                    :sin   => (v::Float64)->  sin(v),
                    :nsin  => (v::Float64)->(-sin(v)),
                    :cos   => (v::Float64)->  cos(v),
                    :ncos  => (v::Float64)->(-cos(v)),
                    :tanh  => (v::Float64)->tanh(v),
                    :sigm  => (v::Float64)->sigmoid(v),
                    :id    => (v::Float64)->id(v)
                }
```

The error I am getting :
ERROR: LoadError: TypeError: in Type, in parameter, expected Type, got Pair{Symbol,getfield(Main, Symbol("##105#113"))}

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the{} need to replaced by ().

Answer (score 0):

As you found out your yourself, the `{}` brackets indicate [type parameters](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/types/#Parametric-Types-1) whereas the paranthesis indicate a [constructor](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/constructors/) call.

Note, that the `::Float64` type annotations aren't necessary for your functions to be performant. Think of them more as a user interface restriction; that is users won't be able to call your methods with non-`Float64`s. However, if you want to specify types explicitly, you could also specify the type of your dictionary explicitly as such `Dict{Symbol, Function}(...)`. However, since you don't initialize the `Dict` empty, Julia will figure out the best type based on your input (symbol function pairs).